# Weird problem: Submit button not showing up in IE8

Tags: html, css, xhtml

On this site: http://tinyurl.com/2allkcs

The submit button for the login form doesn't seem to show up in IE8, however in Firefox it all works just fine.

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your closing `</div>` tag's a little weird, causing problems in chrome as well:

```
<div class="kun-inp-cont"> 
  <input type="password" name="pwd" id="lwa_user_pass" class="kun-inp" value="" /> 
</div
     ><input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="lwa_wp-submit" class="kun-sub" value=" " />
```

Get rid of that extra return that slipped into `</div.....>` and it'll render correctly, currently the browser is discarding that following `<input />` element.

Comment: @Dean - Be sure to mark answers to all of your solved questions as accepted to "close-out" the question and help the next guy, via the check-mark beside the answer that helped resolve the problem :)